# codeigniter join problem

Tags: codeigniter, select, join, where-clause

Hello all i have a problem that when i try to join my comment table it show nothing

here is my code

```
$this->db->select('*,users.profil_billed as profil_billed, forum_traad.id as traad_id');
$this->db->from('forum_traad');
$this->db->join('users', 'forum_traad.brugernavn = users.username');
$this->db->where('forum_traad.fk_forum_kategori', $id);
$this->db->join('forum_kommentare', 'forum_traad.id = forum_kommentare.fk_forum_traad');
$this->db->where('forum_kommentare.fk_forum_traad', 'forum_traad.id');
$this->db->order_by("forum_traad.id", "DESC");
```

its then i put this in it show nothing, and i dont know why.. do i need some left join, right join etc.? i have try all of it :d

```
$this->db->join('forum_kommentare', 'forum_traad.id = forum_kommentare.fk_forum_traad');
$this->db->where('forum_kommentare.fk_forum_traad', 'forum_traad.id');
```

kommentare = comments
traad = thread
brugernavn = username
kategori = categori

its danish,

sorry my bad english hope some one can help me out

---

my database structure is this and im using mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_kategori` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kategori` text NOT NULL,
  `beskrivelse` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `godkendt` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ja',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

CREATE TABLE `forum_kommentare` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_forum_traad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brugernavn` text NOT NULL,
  `indhold` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `dato` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `time` text NOT NULL,
  `godkendt` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ja',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=28;

CREATE TABLE `forum_traad` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `overskrift` text NOT NULL,
  `indhold` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `fk_forum_kategori` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brugernavn` text NOT NULL,
  `dato` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `godkendt` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ja',
  `time` text NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'aaben',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `kon` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `alder` text NOT NULL,
  `hood` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fornavn` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `efternavn` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` text,
  `ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` text,
  `email` text,
  `point` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `oprettet` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `fritekst` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `profil_billed` text NOT NULL,
  `online` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=31;
```

and it return nothing and no errors it only show a message i have done with a else statement that said "there is no threads on this categori", i have try with left join, right join inner join full join, ye all of it :S

Comment: Are you using MySQL? And are there no errors, just no rows returned?

Comment: Show the database structure. SQL format please

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a `left` join on your joins and work from there. If that doesn't work then there isn't a link between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$this->db->select('*,users.profil_billed as profil_billed, forum_traad.id as traad_id');
$this->db->from('forum_traad');
$this->db->join('users', 'forum_traad.brugernavn = users.username');
$this->db->join('forum_kommentare', 'forum_traad.id = forum_kommentare.fk_forum_traad');
$this->db->where('forum_traad.fk_forum_kategori', $id);
$this->db->order_by("forum_traad.id", "DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use after `$this->db->get()` the

```
print $this->db->last_query();
```

and check what's wrong.